# Symfony 4 route to assets folder

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am trying to load the stylesheet in my Assets folder following the instruction giving on this page:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html

But I fail to navigate from the base.html.twig to the folder using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css" />
```

my file structure looks like this:

```
templates 
    base.html.twig 
assets
    css
        style.css
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use symfony's asset function:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" />
```

Comment: does running these commands make a difference? `php app/console cache:clear` 
`php app/console assets:install --symlink`

Comment: Doesn't seem so 
php app/console assets:install --symlink 
Is returning

 [OK] No assets were provided by any bundle.

Answer (score 2):

In your AppExtension:

```
// register function here
public function getFunctions() {
    return [
        new TwigFunction('load_js_asset', array($this, 'fileGetJsAsset')),
    ];
}

// register filter here
public function getFilters() : array
{
    return [
        new TwigFilter('html_entity_decode', 
                       [$this, 'html_entity_decode'], 
                       ['is_safe' => ['html']]),
}

/**
 * @param string $string
 * @return string
 */
public function html_entity_decode(string $string) : string {
    return html_entity_decode($string);
}

/**
 * @param string $file
 * @param bool   $embedScriptTag
 * @return string
 */
public function fileGetJsAsset(string $file, bool $embedScriptTag = true) : string {
    /** @var bool|string $content */
    $content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../assets/js/' . $file);

    if ($content === false) {
        throw new FileException('Could not found or read file: ' . $file);
    }

    if (!$embedScriptTag) {
        return $content;
    }

    return '<script>' . $content . '</script>';
}
```

Now in your view load js assets like this:

// loading from root assets/js folder

`` {{ load_js_asset('core/jquery.min.js', true)|html_entity_decode }}
{{ load_js_asset('core/popper.min.js')|html_entity_decode }}
{{ load_js_asset('my-beauty-js-file.js')|html_entity_decode }}` ``

I hope it helps.

Maybe you will need also htmlspecialchars_decode filter.

Answer (score 0):

http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/best_practices/web-assets.html

Assets function still being usefull in Symfony 4.

Comment: Inside a twig extension file?

Comment: Just in the base

Comment: I got that in the config.yml:

twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

Not sure if will help

Comment: I agree with Ricard Llovet: "Assets is still being usefull in SF4".

What about doing the trick with Twig? It can only be usefull for js files, because css can depend on images, and the path cannot be non public.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possible solutions - without more detail I can't be sure if they will definitely solve the problem or not:

- First, did you configure `webpack-encore` and run the build? Without that the resources won't be there and `nginx` will generate a 404 trying to route to it.
- Second, if you're running with Docker, you may not have mounted the `./app/public/` folder onto the `nginx` container so that the files could be served. If you are getting a Symfony 404 when you go to those files, this may be the issue.